# TypeError: fit() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to write a pipeline consisting of only a single classifier, and failing horribly.

I get the error in the title by running this:

```
myclass = MyClass(path1, path2)
skl_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('myclass', myclass)])
skl_pipeline.fit(None)
```

It doesn't matter what arguments I give it, so I just wrote None as an example.

This is my class definiton:

```
class MyClass (BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
```

And my "fit" function:

```
def fit( self, X = None, y = None ):
    return self
```

It literally couldn't be any simpler.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Full example:

```
class MyClass (BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):

    def __init__(self, FilePath1, FilePath2):
        self.fp1 = FilePath1
        self.fp2 = FilePath2

    #Return self nothing else to do here    
    def fit( self, X = None, y = None ):
        return self 

    def transform( self, X, y = None ):
        return X
```

Comment: just a code style sugestion: variables should be lower case instead of camel case: instead of `FilePath1` goes `file_path1`. In addition to this, and more important, according to sckit learn guides, attributes must be named after their variables, so it should be `self.file_path1 = file_path1`. [checkout docs here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your estimator before passing it to `Pipeline`. This should work:

```py
skl_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('MyClass', MyClass()])
skl_pipeline.fit(None)
```

Comment: This works for me. Please update the question with a complete, runable example showing the problem.